# bouquet of n circles with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw bouquet of n circles. How can i draw it in  Tikz?

[image]

rose with four petals is like i want to draw but with n petals.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing what you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document. Also some graphic of what you want to achieve might be helpful.

Comment: Please provide us with a MWE (minimal working example) to show your effort. The last resort, just provide us with the hand-made sketch to show what you want to draw.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Could you provide more description, or at least an example of image? With a bit of more information we might help you better.

Comment: In addition to the answers already given a [post on TeXample](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/rose-rhodonea-curve/) may be helpful.

Comment: This is a great question.  I needed to draw the same thing myself and found this very useful.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Some inspiration for an answer:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{polaraxis}[grid=none, axis lines=none]
     \addplot[mark=none,domain=0:360,samples=300] {cos(x*3)};
   \end{polaraxis}
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which gives us

[image: Image 1]

And courtesy of my buddy percusse:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{polaraxis}
     \addplot[mark=none,domain=0:360,samples=300] {cos(5*x)};
   \end{polaraxis}
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Image 2]

It's important to observe that the secret relies in

```
cos(n*x)
```

where `n` is the number of petals you want. But note that when `n` is odd, you will end up with `n` petals, and `2n` petals when `n` is even. If somebody could improve the code, it would be great. `:)`

**Update:** tohecz provided me an alternate plot which surely helps us here. Although he claims it's not a smooth curve, it's good enough for me. `:)`

Let's replace

```
cos(n*x)
```

by

```
abs(cos(n*x/2))
```

and voilà!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

 \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{polaraxis}[grid=none, axis lines=none]
     \addplot[mark=none,domain=0:360,samples=300] { abs(cos(6*x/2))};
   \end{polaraxis}
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

And we have:

[image: Image 3]

Yay! `:)`

Comment: Very nice, Paulo +3 ;-)

Answer (score 9):

There are 4 options in PSTricks.

### `r = f(Θ)` in algebraic

Radial distance is a function of angle in algebraic form.

```
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(1,1)
    \psplot[algebraic,polarplot,linecolor=red]{0}{TwoPi}{cos(3*x)}
\end{pspicture}
```

### `x = f(t)` and `y = g(t)` in algebraic

Both `x` and `y` are functions of `t` in algebraic form.

```
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(1,1)
    \psparametricplot[algebraic,linecolor=green]{0}{TwoPi}{cos(3*t)*cos(t)|cos(3*t)*sin(t)}
\end{pspicture}
```

### `r = f(Θ)` in RPN

Radial distance is a function of angle in RPN form.

```
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(1,1)
    \psplot[polarplot,linecolor=blue]{0}{TwoPi RadtoDeg}{3 x mul cos}
\end{pspicture}
```

### `x = f(t)` and `y = g(t)` in RPN

Both `x` and `y` are functions of `t` in RPN form.

```
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(1,1)
    \psparametricplot[linecolor=orange]{0}{TwoPi RadtoDeg}{3 t mul cos t PtoC}
\end{pspicture}
```

### Complete Code

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\psset{plotpoints=150}

\def\Label#1{\uput[90](0,1){\tiny$n=#1$}}

\def\Draw#1{%
% r = f(Θ) in algebraic
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(1,1)
    \psplot[algebraic,polarplot,linecolor=red]{0}{TwoPi}{cos(#1*x)}
    \Label{#1}
\end{pspicture}
% x = f(t) and y = g(t), both are in algebraic
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(1,1)
    \psparametricplot[algebraic,linecolor=green]{0}{TwoPi}{cos(#1*t)*cos(t)|cos(#1*t)*sin(t)}
    \Label{#1}
\end{pspicture}
% r = f(Θ) in RPN
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(1,1)
    \psplot[polarplot,linecolor=blue]{0}{TwoPi RadtoDeg}{#1 x mul cos}
    \Label{#1}
\end{pspicture}
% x = f(t) and y = g(t), both are in RPN
\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(1,1)
    \psparametricplot[linecolor=orange]{0}{TwoPi RadtoDeg}{#1 t mul cos t PtoC}
    \Label{#1}
\end{pspicture}}

\begin{document}
\multido{\i=1+1}{5}{\Draw{\i}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There is one more  option. I will let you know later. This comment will be deleted later.

Comment: n=4 is not correct

Comment: @percusse: Why? TikZ also produces the same output.

Comment: @percusse: Mathematica also produces the same output, see [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nXSgp.png). Your intuition is not correct. :-)

Comment: n=4 does not give 4 petals. read paulos answer

Comment: @percusse: Oh I see. Actually I did not focus on the function when writing the code. I just skimmed through Paulo's answer and took `cos(n*x)` as the function. The remaining update in his answer was fully ignored. :-) Sorry Paulo for my bad!