# Draw a flower like this in Latex

Tags: diagrams

The picture is the following:

[image]

What would be the latex equivalent code ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The short answer is that, yes, it is possible to do this *but* I have to warn you that questions of the form "Please draw this for me", which show no effort on the part of OP, often don't get answered. You will get more help if you post some code showing what you have tried and give a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). A quick search on TeX.SX for drawing functions (with tikz or pstricks) will give you an idea of where to start from.

Comment: There is a similar example here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141624/bouquet-of-n-circles-with-tikz

Comment: @cehptr :-). We are here to help each other because we do not have to be selfish but always leave some good memories.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Sebastian, an answer would be:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{polaraxis}[grid=none, axis lines=none]
     \addplot[mark=none,domain=0:360,samples=300] {0.1 +  abs(cos(4*x/2))};
   \end{polaraxis}
   \node at (3.45, 3.45) {$\mathcal{O}$};
   \node at (3.45, 5.45) {\small{\textbf{(0,2)}}};
   \node at (3.45, 4.8) {\small{\textbf{(0,9)}}};
   \node at (5.25, 3.65) {\small{(8, i)}};
   \node at (5.25, 3) {\small{(8, 10i)}};
   \node at (1.65, 3.65) {\small{(2i+7, i)}};
   \node at (1.65, 3) {\small{(2i+7, 10i)}};
   \node at (3.45, 2.1) {\small{(9i+7,i)}};
   \node at (3.45, 1.45) {\small{(9i+7,10i)}};
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Please also put preamble and figure; can you do it?